# vb.net get an only one datatable row value cell and compare it with a textbox

Tags: vb.net, datatable, textbox, comparison, row

How to get a only one datatable row cell value ? i need to comparison it with a textbox.
Like this:

```
If dttest.Rows.Count < 2 Then
                For counter As Integer = 0 To dttest.Rows.Count - 1
                    If TextBox1.Text = MyDataTable.Rows(1).RowName ' but doesn't accept this format
                        Process.Start("http:\\www.google.it")
                    End If
                Next
            End If
```

**UPDATE** Full code:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private dttest As DataTable
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim dvtest As New DataView
        dvtest = dttest.DefaultView
        dvtest.RowFilter = "test Like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.DataSource = Getdata()
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "test"
    End Sub

    Private Function Getdata() As Object
        dttest = New DataTable()
        dttest.Columns.Add("test", GetType(String))
        dttest.Rows.Add("test1")
        dttest.Rows.Add("test2")
        Return dttest
    End Function
End Class
```

How can i get a single row value, for example, the dttest.Rows.Add(**"test1"**) ?

Comment: row does not have name, columns does, MyDataTable.Rows(1)(0).ColumnName

Comment: What make you think that rows in a `DataTable` have names? As you found out when you tried to code it, a `DataRow` doesn't have a RowName or a Name property.

Comment: but it's possible to get it ? Like i have a column called test , and now i like to get a single  row value, i know the syntax of column but that i have rows too in this format dttest.rows.add("name of the row or value") and these data are loading on listbox through get data, if you wanna i can show you the code, if it can be helpfull :)

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking. A `DataTable` has both rows and columns. Columns have names, but rows do not. When you talk about "a single row value" do you mean the value of the first (or perhaps only) cell in the row?

Comment: @Blackwood yes, like to compare if the text the user put  into the textbox is egual to a only one, row cell value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DataTable looks like this :

```
 ColumnName1   ColumnName2
 value1        hello
 value2        my name is
 value3        username
```

If you want to compare your `TextBox1.Text` with the 2nd column of the 3rd row, then you can use :

```
Dim searchedValue As String = Nothing    
searchedValue = MyDataTable1.Rows("value3").Item("ColumnName2").ToString 

If TextBox1.Text = searchedValue
    Process.Start("http:\\www.google.it")
End If
```

I hope it helped.

**EDIT :**

```
' First, you create your DataTable with this function
Private Function GetData() As Object
    Dim dttest As New DataTable()
    dttest.Columns.Add("test", GetType(String))
    dttest.Rows.Add("test1")
    dttest.Rows.Add("test2")

    ' If you want to get the first value (firstRow and firstColumn)
    ' MsgBox(dttest.Rows(1).Item(0).ToString) ' you will get test1

    ' If you want to get the second value (secondRow and firstColumn)
    ' MsgBox(dttest.Rows(2).Item(0).ToString) ' you will get test2
Return dttest
End Function
```

Then, when you have to handle the `TextChanged event` on your TextBox1 to know when the user modify the text of your TextBox1.

```
Public Sub textBox1_TextChanged() Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If dttest.Rows.Count <= 2 Then
        For counter As Integer = 0 To dttest.Rows.Count - 1
            If dttest.Rows(counter).Item(0).ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
                Process.Start("http://google.it")
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've only one column and in the example above 2 row, but when i put that, visual basic underline myDataTable.Rows and will change it to datatable.rows like this:
TextBox1.Text =DataTable.Rows(always with underline)("rowName").Item("columnName").ToString

Comment: wait i can show it with a picture, this :
http://s16.postimg.org/kuneqv191/image.png Database.Rows is underlined and when i stay with the mouse on it, a tooltip appear and say:
The reference of a member not shared need a reference to an object

Comment: you just **copy** my code without **understand it**.

In fact, you need to use `dttest` instead of `DataTable`
Same with `"rowName"` should be `"test1"`.
And `"columName"` should be `"test"`.

To resume, i guess it'll be okay if you use this line : `TextBox1.Text = dttest.Rows("test1").Item("test").ToString`

Comment: I have a little problem (and sorry for before, i never learned visual basic, but in these days i try my best to learn it, anyways thanks for the correction :)) when i search the text on textbox (example=test1) if im not wrong the first if (If dttest.Rows.Count < 2 Then) should be ok because the count of the rows is 1 so it's ok, the cycle for is ok too , the problem i think is on the if (If TextBox1.Text = dttest.Rows(1).Item(0).ToString Then) because, when search for ("test1") nothing appen, i try with a label that say ok if condiction is true (Label2.Text = "OK").

Comment: You don't have to use `Rows("test1")` because in my edited answer, there is a `loop` to fetch your rows `programmatically`. The variable counter get the value 0 in the first loop, then it increases to 1 and the loop finally end because the value is superior to dttest.count -1.

Comment: I didn't noticed that row on dttest is gone, but now visual basic underlined the dttest.count with this tooltip: count is not a member of System.Data.Datatable

Comment: You need to count the number of Rows, so you can use : `For counter As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: So, i need to store the rows, on a temp value and then i can use this one?
For counter As Integer = 0 To dttest.count - 1

Comment: No, you have to fetch throw the rows that dttest contains. Don't store the rows, this is useless. You can use `dttest.Rows.Count - 1`, this will count the dttest rows programmatically. You can't use `dttest.count - 1` because **you can't count DataTables**. That's why you need to explain what **you want to count : Rows**

Comment: i think it's ok but the if statement at this point should be true because when the user search for test1 on the datatable appear test1 but nothing happens, if i want to open an offline web page stored on my pc in the webbrowser of the form how should i need to put when the condiction of the if (If TextBox1.Text = dttest.Rows(counter).Item(0).ToString Then) come true ?

Comment: or like when the result was found, the user click on that row and the offline web page open in webbrowser.

Comment: If the DataTable contains the TextBox1.Text, then the condition is True.

Comment: There is a better way to do what you need. You need to handle the TextBox1.TextChanged event. I have edited my answer to show you.

Comment: It's working :D but i can substitute the process.start(www.google.it) with a offline page ?

Comment: i'll search documentation on internet. Maybe you can post another thread for this question